# TouchListView resizes view after drop (CommonsWare)

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Hi all (especially CommonsWare)

I am trying to use the TouchListView of CommonsWare.

The movement of the list items works and looks like it should do when i open the app, but as I move the item around, the views get a different size (Think the size is about the same as the simple_list_item_1).

My row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:ignoreGravity="@+id/icon">
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/grabber"/>
   <TextView
         android:id="@+id/label"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="9dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:textSize="25dip"
         android:ellipsize="marquee"
         android:singleLine="true"/>
   <View
         android:id="@+id/groceryCheckedView"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:background="@color/black"
         android:layout_height="2dp"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
   <View
         android:id="@+id/grocerySeparatorView"
         android:background="@color/red"
         android:layout_height="1dp"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

Pictures to illustrate

[image: illustration]

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea what you are talking about. Perhaps consider attaching screenshots illustrating matters.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry for the badly put question. I have added pictures to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, you have not properly set the `normal_height` attribute on your `TouchListView` (or possibly `expanded_height`). The `normal_height` attribute needs to be set to the height of your rows, which needs to be a fixed value. Your row height is based on `wrap_content`, not knowable in advance.